# Manifest Merger fails after upgrading to Android M

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, android-6.0-marshmallow, manifest-merging

After pointing to the latest manifest-merger.jar provided in the Android M preview and updating my apps to

```
<uses-sdk targetSdkVersion='MNC'>
<uses-sdk minSdkVersion='MNC'>
```

when attempting to use the manifest merger on these apps, I get the following error:

```
EXEC : error : [C:\MyApp\AndroidManifest.xml:3] Failed to parse <uses-sdk targetSdkVersion='MNC'>: must be an integer number or codename.
```

I am using the same command I was for the previous manifest-merger.jar and it used to work fine.

Update1: adding command

```
"F:\bin\JDK.1.7.0.51\bin\java.exe" -classpath "F:\android-MNC-sdk\tools\lib\sdklib.jar;F:\android-MNC-sdk\tools\lib\manifest-merger.jar"  com.android.manifmerger.Main merge --out foo.xml --main app1\AndroidManifest.xml --libs appBase\AndroidManifest.xml
```

Comment: What Gradle for Android plugin version are you using, assuming that you are using Android Studio? This is the `classpath` line in your top-level `build.gradle` file.

Comment: I'm using a company specific build tool and i'm invoking manifest-merger.jar by itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oddly enough, even though it produced this error, it was actually also producing the merged manifest. Definite bug with the 24.3.3 version of manifest-merger.jar

Reported here: https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=2487

Comment: This was acknowledged today.